# Too many database connections mysql

Tags: mysql, shell

I have a shell script to execute some query in mysql database and process the results and send mail accordingly. The script runs 24X7 in each 15 minutes. Inside the shell script I am simply connecting to the db using the command
**'mysql -uusername -ppassword database -s -N -e "Some query goes here"**

All I want to know is that, does this script have to do something with the db connection leak, since I am executing this script forever. 
When I execute the following query I can see that each time the Connections value goes up by one in each 15 minutes. 
show status like '%Con%';

```
+----------------------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name                          | Value |
+----------------------------------------+-------+
| Aborted_connects                       | 4     |
| Com_show_contributors                  | 0     |
| Connections                            | 804   |
| Max_used_connections                   | 152   |
| Performance_schema_cond_classes_lost   | 0     |
| Performance_schema_cond_instances_lost | 0     |
| Ssl_client_connects                    | 0     |
| Ssl_connect_renegotiates               | 0     |
| Ssl_finished_connects                  | 0     |
| Threads_connected                      | 14    |
+----------------------------------------+-------+
```

Does it crash at some point of time?. Because the value never comes down. I know the value indicates the total number of connections present to the db. However Max_used_connections remains same. 
Or is there a way to close the db connection from shell script?

Comment: you have to close the each  connection properly

Comment: You may wish to consider using MySQL events to avoid racking up connections. Read this. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As MySQL documentation on the [connections server status variable](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Connections) says:

> The number of connection attempts (successful or not) to the MySQL server.

So, this is a statistical number showing the number of connection attempts since the last restart of the MySQL server.

The [threads_connected status variable](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Threads_connected) shows the number of currently open connections (14 in your case). If this status variable equals to the [max_connections server SYSTEM variable](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connections), then you will start receiving too many connections error message.

Comment: **The number of connection attempts (successful or not) to the MySQL server** - Does it have any limit? . And **threads_connected** variable has nothing to do with the script , right? Thanks for the reply, I will check the documentation you have pointed.

Comment: It is a statistical number only, it will simply overflow (restart) if the maximum is reached. However, the linked MySQL documentation tells you the data type of the variable, which implies its limit.

Comment: Threads_connected lists all currently open connections. If you run your `show variables` query while your script runs, then the threads_connected variable would include the connection made by the command line client.